# How to get selected checkbox values in controller from formcollection?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, formcollection

I am passing a form collection object to one of my controller via ajax like this.

```
var formCollection = $(':input');
    $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                data: formCollection,
                success: function (result) {
                    // debugger
                    if (result.status == true)
                        document.getElementById('Iframe211').src = "ActivationModal.aspx"

                }
            })
```

and in the controller i am retreiving the values like this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assign(FormCollection form)
    {
       var ch = form.GetValues("Prints");

        }
```

Here prints is the name of the checkbox field which is defined in the webgrid,

The problem here is  in the variable ch i am not getting the values of checkbox which are selected, i am getting all the checkbox values in the array irrespective of whether it is selected or not.

How can i get only the values of checkbox which are selected?

Thanks

Comment: that's becacuse you're passing formCollection which doesn't specifiy whether the checkbox is checked or not. I think you want `var formCollection = $('input:checked')`

Comment: But then will it pass other values inside the form like a hidden field or a dropdown value

Comment: I need to pass all form controls and checkbox values which are checked

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your selector like following

```
var formCollection = $(':input:not(:checkbox), input:checked');
```

This will get all the controls which are not checkbox and then all the checked checkboxes.